# Windows Server 2008: how to switch license of retail version to MAPS and vice-versa?

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing

Is there any way to take an existing VMware virtual Windows Server 2008 machine that was installed with a retail product key, and switch it to a MAPS key? And/or vice-versa? It would be nice to clone our production Web servers to dev ones with the exact same setup (using MAPS).

I've heard they're completely different so it can't be done, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like if it doesn't work from the official interface there's an alternate using a script that's installed in system32:

http://forevergeeks.com/change-product-key-on-windows-server-2008

Comment: I'll have to try this and will post what I find out. Again, the issue is with a MAPS key.

Comment: Just did a re-install so don't know whether it worked or not.